# Tcp communication client

Tags: vb.net, tcp, binary, tcpclient

I am stuck in a situation , my application needs to connect to a server using TCP . For connection request it needs to send a packet with following configuration:

```
8bits - Protocol - value - 01
8bits - Command - value - 01
16bits - Data length
32bits - Data
8bits- Reserve Bit
```

I am using .Net Tcp Client to send the data. I don't know how to send the data in binary mode

Comment: I assume that you mean "For communication" rather than "For connection".  In .NET, "binary" means using a `Byte` array.  Once you've made you connection, You can call `Write` on the provided `NetworkStream` and pass a `Byte` array containing your data. To get binary data, you can use `Encoding.GetBytes` for text and the `BitConverter` class for numeric types.

Comment: I don't know whether you're actually supposed to use bits or bytes, but for the record 8 bits = 1 byte.